# Ajax no llama a controlador Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

Hola tengo problema para llamar a un controlador usando ajax, lo que quiero hacer es ir a otra pagina mediante ajax.

```
        function validar(){
            var codigo= $('#codigo').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "/host/validar",
                data: {
                    "codigo" : codigo
                },
                success: function(result) {
                   alert("success");
                },
                error : function(e) {
                   alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
```

el html con thymeleaf

```
<div class="x_content">
<section class="text-center">
    <h5><span>Ingrese codigo</span></h5>
    <form id="formValidar">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="codigo" required="" id="codigo" name="codigo" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
 </section>
</div>
```

y en mi controlador

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String validar(
        @RequestParam("codigo") String codigo){
    System.out.println("entro sdgsdgdsg");
    System.out.println("codigo: "+codigo);
    Usuario usuario = usuarioService.buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
    if (usuario == null){
       return "pagina-validar";
    }
    return "nueva-pagina";
}
```

Tengo agregada la anotacion @Controller en la clase, y tengo otro ejemplo casi el mismo en otra clase y si me funciona, pero este ni siquiera entra al método.

Comment: En la peticion Ajax llamas a /host/validar y en Spring tienes mapeado /validar. O tu aplicacion funciona dentro del contexto "/host" o normal que no te pase por la la direccion mapeada. De todos modos, ¿ te salta el alert de error de ajax ?

Comment: @chuchip Me he dado cuenta que como es una pagina al que cualquiera puede acceder, pero si uno esta logeado y por url va a esa pagina si entra al controlador, pero si no lo esta, no llama al controlador.